Redirection Issue with Trailing Slashes in React JS App
I'm experiencing a redirection issue in my React JS app where main pages are being redirected to their respective directory paths with a trailing slash (/), resulting in 301 redirect issues.
What I tried:
Configured .htaccess file to prevent trailing slash redirects:
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
...

Expected: No redirection to directory paths with trailing slashes. But I am getting one.
https://example.com/about/
https://example.com/about
